# Getting the Max value of a column in a database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the max value of a column in a database table.

This is my PHP:

```
$st = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT max(`version`) FROM `remembers` WHERE id='$id'"));
$version = $st['version'] + 1;
```

So that should get the current version of `id` and then update it but adding 1 to it. But `$st['version']` seems to be returning `0` when in the database the current highest is `1`

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to archive this?

Comment: Can you show us the table structure?

Comment: id typically suggests a primary key so there would only be one version.. right?

Comment: Id in this case is just a 7 character string of random letters and numbers

Comment: It's 2012 and `mysql_query` wants to go into retirement. Please **DO NOT USE** these methods in new code as they are being deprecated and may be removed. Switching to `mysqli` or PDO is a small investment of time that will save you immeasurable amounts of pain, suffering and/or embarrassment caused by [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php). In your example you're apparently praying that `$id` can be evaluated without harm and faith based programming is never a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to alias the `MAX()` selection in SQL in order to reference it in PHP:

```
SELECT max(`version`) AS version FROM ...
```

Also, `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an array of arrays, so you cannot simply reference `$st['version']` directly. Instead, you can change your PHP to:

```
$st = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT max(`version`) AS version FROM `remembers` WHERE id='$id'"));
$version = $st[0] + 1;
```

Comment: Even when adding the AS keyword. Now `$st['version']` is returning nothing

Comment: @Shawn31313 try running the raw query in phpMyAdmin and see what it returns.

Comment: hmm, it does get the max value for that column, so I don't see why the fetch wont work :/

Comment: @Shawn31313 it's also because `mysql_fetch_assoc` is returning an array of arrays, so you cannot just reference `$st['version']` directly. See my updated solution.

Comment: I found the issue, it wouldn't allow me to add the mysql_query unless its in a variable.. thats weird.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a function call max() and you are using it in the right context.
You are so close to doing it right!

You just need to use the AS keyword.

SELECT max(`version`) AS max_version FROM `remembers` WHERE id='$id'